Small deviation asymptotics for sub-gaussian diffusions in dirichlet spaces
Let $(X,d,\mu)$ be a metric measure space equipped with a strongly local, regular Dirichlet form $(\mathcal{E}, \mathcal{D}(\mathcal{E}))$ on $L^2(X,\mu)$. Assume that the associated heat kernel $p_t(x,y)$ satisfies the following two-sided sub-Gaussian estimate:
$$ c_1 t^{-\alpha/\beta} \Phi \left( c_2 \frac{d(x,y)}{t^{1/\beta}}\right) \leq p_t(x,y) \leq c_3 t^{-\alpha/\beta} \Phi \left( c_4 \frac{d(x,y)}{t^{1/\beta}}\right),$$
where $\alpha>0$, $\beta>1$, $c_i>0$ are constants, and $\Phi:[0,\infty) \to (0,\infty)$ is a continuous, decreasing function. Let $U \subset X$ be a bounded, open set, and let $\tau_U$ be the first exit time from $U$ of the associated Hunt process.
Under what conditions on $\Phi$ and $U$ does the following small deviation asymptotic hold for some constant $C>0$ and all $x \in U$?
$$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \epsilon^\beta \log \mathbb{P}_x (\tau_U > \epsilon^\beta) = -C. $$
Can one characterize the constant $C$ in terms of the geometry of $U$ and the function $\Phi$?

I’m voting to close this question because the pattern of behaviour across several questions from the same account resembles past offenders
